# Using AlertView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I am using AlertView and the xcode, and the xcode shows the message: undeclared identifier alertLabel ...

Here is the code:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *) alerta didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        alertLabel.text = @"Ok!";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: where is `alertLabel` defined?

Comment: `alertLabel`is indeed undefined. your alertView is called `alerta`

Comment: Branch Problem  in your switch case , please check my answer and solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means there is no such thing as alertlabel, so make sure you declared it properly.

Comment: well, i saw the mistake here... i changed the name of the variable and i have forgotten to change the same name on the .h ... thanks :P

Comment: If you right-click a symbol (variable or method name) and choose **Refactor→Rename…**, Xcode will take care of renaming all uses of that symbol, including `setSymbolName:` setters, headers, and even .h and .m file names.

Answer (score 2):

**Using AlertView in iOS**

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@" Running apps in the background " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not have defined AlertLabel properly, check it is initialised properly

Answer (score 0):

If alerta is a label in another viewcontroller which is the delegate of the alert view try this change

```
self.delegate.alertLabel.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you the @property and @synthesize of your alertLabel ?